# probability- when selecting 4 out of 10 officers

Tags: probability

In how many ways can a roster of four club officers be selected from 10 nominees so that the first one selected will be president, the second vice-president, the third secretary, and the fourth treasurer?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose somebody already picked them, then the questions: who is president, who is vicepresident, who is secretary and who is fourth treasurer, should give you the answer.

If you ask them in that order, how many possible answers can you receive for each question?

Spoiler:

> There are 10 for the first, 9 for the second, 8 for third, and 7 for final. So the answer is $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=5040$